# how to decide on multilevel page tables

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory

I am having some doubts on how to decide that how many levels of page table should be taken in virtual address space if we are having 32 bit of logical address space and page size is 4KB??(as sometimes in questions they took only single level and sometimes second level page table so it is confusing)

Question:

we have 36 bit physical address and 32 bit virtual address with page frame size 4KB, each table entry is of 4 Bytes, a three level page table is used for virtual to physical address translation, where In virtual address, bit 30-31 are used to index first level, bit 21-29 to address second level, bit 12-20 to address third level and bit 0-11 as offset in page, so what should be the no. of bits required for addressing the next level page table**(or page frame)**  in the page table entry of the first, second, and third level page tables??

please help
thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you have an actual question, problem or task? Currently your question is too vague and is risking to be closed as either "not a real question" or "not constructive". Can you elaborate the question?

Comment: I have given a proper question..@AlexeyFrunze

Comment: First off, the updated question radically differs from the original question and it has different numbers. You should formulate your questions in a way that you don't have to rewrite them OR you should ask different questions separately. Next, it seems like you're now describing x86 32-bit mode page translation with PAE (in the original question it was non-PAE). It is a fixed scheme with table indices being 2-bit, 9-bit and 9-bit (totaling 20) just as you describe it. And that's it. I have no idea what you mean by the "next level page table". Next to what? Where?

Comment: actually in Gate 2008 this questions is asked, it is asking no. of bits required for addressing the next level page table(or page frame) in the page table entry of the first, second, and third level page tables?? i am not getting how to solve this question...@AlexeyFrunze

Comment: There's one thing I don't quite understand. When a page table is indexed with a 9-bit index, the table has at most 512 accessible entries. With 4-byte entries that gives you 2 KB worth of accessible PTEs in a page table page. That's only a half of the page size. Are you sure there isn't any mistake or typo in your numbers? I'd expect page tables to occupy an integral number of pages. For example, the x86 32-bit PAE scheme, which is very similar to what you're describing in the question, has 8-byte PTEs, not 4-byte.

Comment: the data i have given is as it was given in Gate.. what i have understood is as page size is 4KB Therefore number of bits required to access a page is 12, The physical memory size is 36 bits and page size is 4KB. therefore number of bits required to address the  physical memory frames is  24. In the second and third levels, 9 bits are used to index in to the tables and each entry size is 4 bytes.
the size of pages in the second and third level are 2^9 * 4 = 2^11. Now after this I am not getting how to solve the problem..

Answer (score 0):

The problem/question as stated lacks necessary information to be answered definitively.

The answer could be 24, 24, and 24 bits and then every page table would waste half of the page where it's stored.

Or the answer could be 25, 25, 24 but then every page table would occupy less than the page size.

Or it could be a more extravagant answer like 24,25,24 or 25,24,24.

Either way, it would be a very odd arrangement, insufficiently logical to be chosen as the answer.

See a discussion [here](https://www.gatementor.com/viewtopic.php?f=267&t=5070).

Comment: in 24,24,24 as the answer, they have taken 24 bit entries in first and second level page tables because in third level we have 24 bit entries but first level will give the address for second leve table so how can we take 24 bit in first, **the 24 in third level is justified but in second and first how it is justified**

Comment: I told you, there are multiple possible answers and there isn't enough information to choose the definitive winner. There just isn't much basis to justify or strongly advocate for any one answer.